# How to Return a Promise from a Unirest PUT Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, unirest

I am trying to create a function that returns a promise so it can be chained together and integrated with some other functions.

When I try to run, I get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Can I put the promise inside `.end` or does it need to be wrapped around the entire function body?  Can errors be properly handled like this?

index.js

```
const module = require('./module');

var test = {
  name: "Full Name"
};

module.update(test).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

module.js

```
const unirest = require('unirest');

module.exports = {

update: function({name}) {
  unirest.put(someURL)
    .headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
    .send({
      name: name
    })
    .end(function (response) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(response) {
          resolve(response)
        }
        if(error){
          reject(response)
        }
      })
  });
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root of your function should be the one returning the promise.

```
update: function(name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    unirest.put(someURL)
      .headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
      .send({
        name: name
      })
      .end(function (response) {
        if(response) {
          resolve(response)
        }
        if(error){
          reject(response)
        }
      })
  });
}
```